# How exclude fields from _source with spring data elasticsearch?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

The `@Query` annotation contains no options for this.
I can't add -

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "id",
      "name",
      "address"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Projections don't work in ES repositories.

The only way is to make your own repository (`NativeSearchQuery` and ect.) or DTO?
Why can't these things be made easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the query implementations from Spring Data Elasticsearch have the possibility to set a source filter.

The `@Query` annotation can only contain the query part as you wrote, there is already [a ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2062) to make this more flexible.

> Why can't these things be made easier?

Well, Spring Data Elasticsearch is a community driven project, so if you want to contribute to it, you are welcome.